# Couldn't install librosa on windows

Tags: python, windows, installation, pycharm, librosa

i tried to install librosa on Pycharm (windows)but i had this error:

ERROR: Could not build wheels for soxr, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based projects

I used all three following commands and no one worked:

pip innstall librosa

pip install -u librosa

Comment: sudo in Windows?

Answer (score 0):

Try installing through command prompt, if it works then install it in your virtual environment, else
Try this

```
pip3 install librosa -u
```

if it still doesn't work then,

Make sure to have the right versions of pip and setuptools

```
pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel
```

And btw 'sudo' command is used for admin perm only in linux systems and doesn't work in windows!!!

Comment: Didn't work unfrotunately, and for the first one i got this :no such option: -u